# C++ function and array homework

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Create a function that prints the array to the screen as a table with the appropriate rows and columns. Use setw() to ensure the numbers have enough room. You may assume the numbers are no more than 3 digits each. Include the row and column labels.

In main, ask the user to supply a row and column and a value (no more than 3 digits), then put the value into the array at that row and column. Print the result and ask the user for another row, column and value. Repeat until the user is finished.

Once finished, compute and print the total of the values in the array.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    const int ROWS= 4;
    const int COLS = 3;
    const int WIDTH = 4;
    const char YES = 'y';
    int total = 0;

    void print(int arr[ROWS][COLS]);

    int main()
    {
      int arr[ROWS][COLS];
      char ans = YES;
      int val;

      for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++){
       for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
         arr[r][c] = 0;}
    while (tolower(ans) == YES){
      int row = -1;
      int col = -1;
      cout << "Row? ";
      cin >> row;
      cout << "Columns? ";
      cin >> col;

      while (row < 0 || row >=ROWS){
        cout << "Only value under " << ROWS << " is accepted, try again: ";
        cin >> row;
     }
      while (col < 0 || col >= COLS){
        cout << "Only value under " << COLS << "is accepted, try again: ";
        cin >> col;
     }

     cout << "Value? ";
     cin >> val;
     arr[row][col] = val;
     print(arr);

     cout << "Again (y/n)? ";
     cin >> ans;
     }

     for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++){
       for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++){
         total += arr[r][c];
       }
     }
     cout << "Sum of all values is " << total << endl;

    // Print array with labels
    // get input from user
    // print array again - repeat until user wishes to quit

    return 0;
    }

    void print (const int arr[ROWS][COLS])
    {
        cout << endl << endl;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < COLS; i++)
        cout << setw(WIDTH) << i;
        cout << endl;
      for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
        cout << setw(WIDTH) << r << "|";
    for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c< COLS; c++)
          cout << setw(WIDTH) << arr[r][c];
          cout << endl << endl;
    }
```

I dont know where I did wrong on this one but when I complie, I got the LD return 1 exit status error, Can you please help?

Comment: What is the full error message? LD makes it sound like compile/link time rather than runtime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the declaration of your `print()` function.

```
 void print(int arr[ROWS][COLS]);
```

to

```
 void print(const int arr[ROWS][COLS]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition and the declaration of your print function are different.

Comment: Top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored in determining function signature; `void f(int);` and `void f(const int);` are the same function. The problem is that this doesn't extend to the OP's case, because the `const` isn't actually top-level, hence the linker error.

Comment: well, according to msvc2013 having different signatures is a link problem: main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl print(int (* const)[3])" (?print@@YAXQAY02H@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: Yes, because they are treated as two overloads.